# FourierTransform is really inverse Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

New Mathematica user here.  I was trying to use `FourierTransform` today and getting perplexing minus signs in places I didn't expect them.  After perusing the documentation, it seems to be due to the fact that what Mathematica calls `FourierTransform` is actually an inverse Fourier transform by the usual definition.

Questions:

> Why is it defined like this?
>
> There are of course many different conventions for Fourier transforms (angular vs. regular frequency, normalizations, etc.).  Is there somewhere I can find a summary of Mathematica conventions?

Comment: This was addressed in some depth [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118092).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line in definition can be a little misleading. You need to look down more

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When comparing it to the more standard one with minus sign

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But that is because , down in the same help page we see

[image]

And the above is the one you want to use, to change the definition to the way you want it.

I normally use `FourierParameters->{1,-1}` which gives standard one used in signal processing with the minus sign as expected. I have these `FourierParameters->{1,-1}` written on a yellow stick note attached to the corner of computer screen so I do not forget them because there are others.

So using `FourierParameters->{1,-1}` in the above gives

$$
   F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{- i \omega t} \,dt
$$

which is what our text in DSP uses. Hence your code should be like this

```
 FourierTransform[f[t], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

And not just

```
 FourierTransform[f[t], t, w]
```

This way there will be no surprises.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any idea why the default is the way it is?  I have never seen a definition of Fourier transform without a minus in the exponent anywhere else.  This seems like a really insidious gotcha.

Comment: @Yly I do not know. Mathematica is almost 30 years old. May be at the time they wrote this back in the days, the other definition was more popular? I really do not know., But I always use `FourierParameters` this way, I always know which definition I am using.

Comment: @Yly - that's the definition for physics.

Comment: `that's the definition for physics`. @Yly well, this explains it then. Wolfram is a Physicist, so may be he is the one who wrote the above help page. Now we know who to blame :)